# How to readibly visualize four related streams of network data?

Tags: data-visualization, excel

I have network data coming from four different data streams simultaneously, and would like to visualize the data on some sort of concurrent timeline so I can identify potentially related events.  I have thousands of data points coming from each stream.  I am not sure the best way to present this data, or if I need to process it in an alternative fashion.

Here is some sample data, comma separated:

```
Source ID,Event,Date,Start,Duration (s),Offset,Std Start Time,Actual Start Time,Actual End Time

1,Sync Error,7/3/2015,11:10:27.1,2.0,0:00:02,7/3/2015 11:10:25.1,7/3/2015 11:10:23.1,7/3/2015 11:10:25.1

1,Data Error,7/3/2015,11:10:27.1,0.1,0:00:02,7/3/2015 11:10:25.1,7/3/2015 11:10:25.1,7/3/2015 11:10:25.2

3,Data Error,7/3/2015,15:56:44.1,0.1,0:00:04,7/3/2015 15:56:40.1,7/3/2015 15:56:40.1,7/3/2015 15:56:40.2
```

To explain the data, different error types report at different times.  Data errors have no duration, so always report 0.1 second, while sync errors report after they have been resolved, so their 'start' time is actually the end time.  This is why there is an actual column for both start and end time.  Offset is to account for time differences between servers.

I originally tried creating a Gantt chart with all the data cascading as unique events, but this quickly became unmanageable due to the sheer volume of data.

Ideally, I would like a timeline that has four bars, one for each source.  I would like a visual for each instance where multiple sources have errors that occur within some timeframe (two streams have an error within 0.5 seconds of each other).

My instinct is to use Python or another scripting language to parse the data (which I'm capable of) and identify the overlaps to slice the data, and then use something I do not yet know of to graph the data.

Does anyone know how I can handle all this through Excel, preferably, or if there is another program I should use?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Excel charting ([Jon Peltier's site](http://peltiertech.com/) is a good resource for Excel) but you should be able to apply some preprocessing and get Excel to make something like the chart below as a Gantt chart or horizontal stacked bar chart.

[image]

In my fake data, I encoded each time slice as one of three states, each corresponding to a different color: no error, lone error, error coincident with other errors.

Comment: The main preprocessing action was: for each stream, I inserted records for the non-error times. Those are the gray bars. Then I could change the start/end times to just durations and stack them.